# Masonry layout (sometimes) adds 1px gutter between items

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, jquery-masonry

I've got 7 items layed out with Masonry. Depending on the screen dimensions sometimes a 1px gutter (white space) in between the 2nd row and 3rd row appears (and sometimes also between the 2nd and 3rd column).

Personally I do not want to have space in between the tiles/items. Who knows what causes this single px line to appear and how this can be resolved?

Example: http://wallstart.nl/test.html

Resulting in: https://infinit.io/_/fJqNxKq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't set height on items so their height calculated based on:

```
padding: 10%;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 1.5em;
```

font-size is ok but padding and line-height(because percentage and em) on items causes the height to have floating-point numbers(etc. `height: 70.83px`). But I think position of the items calculated from those numbers' ceiled values. (etc. `top: 71px`). So it looks weird on some zoom levels.

If these is no support or fix for this in this library I would try to override padding and line-height on `.grid-item a` to have pixel values.